# How to to get rid of outlines of light in my render?

Tags: rendering

When I do the image render preview for my animation, I can see the light outlines in my image. Does anyone know how to get these to go away but still have the light be there and emitting light?

Thank you[image: here is the image showing the light outlines in the render]

Comment: Did you try disabling overlays? You can find the button (two circles, one filed and one outlined intersecting) in the top right (or bottom right depending on your settings) of the viewport header.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to disable the line in render, for that click the funnel icon in the top right of your screen,

Comment: thank you this was useful